# Getting nullpointexception on selenium using TestNg Cucumber

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java, null-pointer, testng.xml

I am getting null pointerException when i try to run my selenium code using TestNG. I have configured as below. Please let me know how to resolve this issue

Below is my runner class i have used

**Runner class**

```
package com.BDD.Runner;


import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import cucumber.api.testng.CucumberFeatureWrapper;
import cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

//@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources/Features",glue= {"com.BDD.StepDef"},monochrome=true,
        plugin= {"pretty","html:target/HtmlReports/index.html",
                "json:target/JsonReports/report.json"},tags="@test")

public class CucumberRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{

}
```

Below is the configuration done on xml file

**TestNG XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="BDD_TestNG">
      <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.BDD.Runner.CucumberRunner" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite> <!-- BDD_TestNG -->
```

I am getting below error when i try to run tstng.xml through TestNG suite

**Console output**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.features(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:74)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:45)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:131)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:706)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:49)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:37)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:924)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
BDD_TestNG
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 2, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Need check code line of AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:29

Null point exception detecting when we do not instantiate driver properly for every class

Comment: create a global variable for webdriver